# ¿TextAreaFor puede guardar datos de la misma manera que EditorFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Hola a todos comunidad

Voy a contar lo que estoy haciendo para que entiendan el contexto de mi pregunta.

Estoy editando un formulario creado con entity framework y estoy usando c#, la cuestión es que hay un campo en donde el framework por defecto te crea un EditorFor y guarda los datos de manera normal en la bdd, pero, terminé usando un TextAreaFor  debido a que es mas maleable en cuanto a su aspecto, y el problema es el siguiente, al usar el TextAreaFor no me capta lo que estoy introduciendo en dicho campo para poder guardar en la bdd , podrían ayudarme con esa duda? si hay alguna manera de editar el EditorFor tambien me vendría bien, muchas gracias de antemano.

Acá dejo el como estoy escribiendo el campo.

```
  @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Descripcion_Producto, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", rows = 4, cols = 20 })
```

Comment: Intentaste poner un breakpoint y fijarte si el dato llega al Controller? Estaría bueno que agregues el método del Controller que procesa el formulario..

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal , el guarda bien , mi error era por haber escrito mal el nombre de la variable u_u jeje . Muchas gracias de todas formas con la ayuda.